# Iterate over result set converted to objects array

Tags: java, collections, apache-poi

I have converted the Resultset to Objects. Now I would like to iterate over the finalResult. Actually I want to write this finalResult array to Excel. Can anyone please suggest how to do that.

```
public Object[][] executeQuery(String query) throws SQLException{
    ResultSet rs = getResultSet(query);
    ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnCount = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();
    ArrayList<Object[]> result = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    Object[] header = new Object[columnCount];
    for (int i=1; i <= columnCount; ++i){
        Object label = rsMetaData.getColumnLabel(i);
        header[i-1] = label;
    }
    while (rs.next()){
        Object[] str = new Object[columnCount];
        for (int i=1; i <= columnCount; ++i){
            Object obj = rs.getObject(i);
            str[i-1] = obj;
        }
        result.add(str);
    }
    int resultLength = result.size();
    Object[][] finalResult = new Object[resultLength][columnCount];
    finalResult[0] = header;
    for(int i=1;i<resultLength;++i){
        Object[] row = result.get(i);
        finalResult[i] = row;
    }
    return finalResult;
}
```

Comment: You're missing the first item from your result set. You need an object of resultLength+1 rows (to include the header) and then start i from 0 when you use result.get(i).

Answer (score -1):

For writing as Excel file, have a look at Apache POI. Here's the link to the (excellent!) busy programmer's guide: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html

Look at the topics for creating a workbook, creating a sheet and creating cells.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest, and quickest, way to get your data into Excel is to write the results to a comma separated values file or CSV. Excel can load this format natively. Each line of text contains a series of fields separated by a comma. This file will not include formulas or formatting but your data will be present. You can a header field if so you choose.

```
header1,header2
value1,value2
```

This file is a plain text file so there are no libraries required.